# BufferedReader specific line not being appended to String

Tags: java, android, html, string, bufferedreader

I am using BufferedReader to read the lines of an InputStream from an HttpURLConnection. Everything is working as expected, except for a single line that is giving me trouble.

The specific line is as follows:

> ```
>     <span class="dbox-italic">Chemistry.</span>            <ol class="def-sub-list">
> ```

The code I am using is as follows:

```
        URL searchUrl;
        ArrayList<String> definitions = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            searchUrl = new URL("http://dictionary.com/browse/" + word);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) searchUrl.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; Vodafone Smart ultra 6"
                    + " Build/LMY47V) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.91"
                    + " Mobile Safari/537.36");

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String line;

            while((line = in.readLine()) != null){
                if(line.contains("class=\"def-content\"")){
                    line = in.readLine();

                    if(line.contains("</div>")){
                        int endIndex = line.indexOf("</div>") - 11;
                        String definition = line.trim().substring(0, endIndex);
                        definitions.add(definition);
                    } else {
                        if(line.contains("class=\"def-sub-list\"")){
                            String sublist = line;

                            while(!line.contains("</ol>")){
                                line = in.readLine();
                                sublist += line;
                            }

                            sublist = sublist.replaceAll("<li>", "").replaceAll("</ol>", "").trim();

                            String[] sublistDefinitions = sublist.split("</li>");

                            for(String definition : sublistDefinitions){
                                definition.trim();
                                definitions.add(definition);
                            }

                        }

                    }


                }
            }

            System.out.print("");

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The problem line of code is this one:

```
String sublist = line;
```

That line of code works with this line of HTML (I had to use a screenshot because StackOverflow wouldn't let me just quote the HTML without removing the tags, which is useful information):

[image]

But not this line:

> ```
>     <span class="dbox-italic">Chemistry.</span>            <ol class="def-sub-list">
> ```

I've tried removing the ">" at the end, but it's as if Java refuses to manipulate that one line in any way. No matter how many characters I took off the end after trimming the whitespace, the line stayed exactly as it's shown above (minus the whitespace). Could it be that the problem line ends with an invisible special character such as a newline, and Java doesn't like that?

Comment: Have you looked into using https://jsoup.org/ ? May make your life a bit easier.

Comment: I like the challenge of building my own Web Crawlers, but I might have to use Jsoup for this one.

Comment: I did attempt to reproduce your problem, but had no luck. If you're able make it clearer I can take another look :)

Comment: I've decided to just use Jsoup for this one. The functionality I wanted is up and running now.